# Image not shown when java compiled

Tags: java, image, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

Currently, I having a trouble with `Dynamicreports`.

I have these packages, classes, and images:

```
 com.reports
  - GenerateReport.java
  .
  .
 com.resources
  - logo.gif
  .
  .
```

Now, the GenerateReport.java would generate a specific report containing LOGO and data.
The logo is `logo.gif` located in `com.resources`.

If I run that java file, it would generate the report with the LOGO and data. So, there is no problem.

My problem is when I compile the file and run the jar file, it would generate containing the data BUT the logo wouldn't appear anymore.

The code is this:

```
cmp.image(GenerateReport.class.getResource("../resources/logo.gif"))
```

Where should I change?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this in my web-application, But make sure you are getting that image, for that make required souts for printing file path.

```
   ImageBuilder image = cmp.image(imageUrl);
```

and used this 'image' component in horizontalList

```
   cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.hListCell(image));
```

It works fine, just make sure that your imageUrl path is correct.